# LINQ to SQL query to populate ListBox returns wrong results

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

Hello here's a LINQ to SQL query :

```
    private void Stk_DT_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;

        #region Buttons Picking Libres
        using(BdCretsDataContext dc=new BdCretsDataContext())
        {
            var placement = (from p in dc.PICKING
                             where p.ART_CODE == ArtCode_TxtBox.Text
                             select new { p.R_PLACEMENT }).Distinct().ToList();
            LB.ItemsSource = placement;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

With this query I want to fill a `ListBox`. But I get this result :

[image: Resuslt]

All I want is just:  *53*.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that `select new { p.R_PLACEMENT }` creates a collection of objects that have a property called `R_PLACEMENT`. The `ToString()` of this object, which is invoked by the `ListBox`, returns a string representation of this object: `{ R_PLACEMENT = 53 }`. You have to unwrap or collect the values from this property:

```
LB.ItemsSource = placement.Select(row => row.R_PLACEMENT);
```

This returns a collection of *values* only.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you create a new (anonymous) type within `select new { p.R_PLACEMENT }`.
Your `placement` variable will thus hold a `List<>` of this new type. The `ListBox` however does not know how to display items of this type.

To make the `ListBox` display something useful you must tell it what it should make out of this anonymous type. `ListBox` does not figure out it on its own.

The simplest solution would probably be to create `placement` like this:

```
var placement = (from p in dc.PICKING
                             where p.ART_CODE == ArtCode_TxtBox.Text
                             select p.R_PLACEMENT.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
```

(From your example I deduce that `R_PLACEMENT` is of some numeric type.) The `.ToString()` suffix makes `placement` a `List<string>` which the `ListBox` will be glad to display correctly.

Comment: This is not true. You are mixing it up. What you mean is that when the `ListBox` doesn't know how to template the data, it will by default call the `ToString()` member of the data type. When `ToString()` is not overridden then it returns the fully qualified type name. Here, as you said, the query creates an anonymous type. This type has a property `R_PLACEMENT` and a value. The `ToString()` of this anonymous object returns a string representation of this object: `{ R_PLACEMENT = 53 }`. The solution would be to collect the values of each row using `Enumerable.Select`.